# How can I use event.preventDefault with typeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

I have a TypeScript, React/next.js application.  I am trying to setup react-hook-form for the validation.  I have imported useForm and SubmitHandler from react hook form, created an interface, and also created a function.

```
import {useForm, SubmitHandler} from 'react-hook-form';

interface Inputs {
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
email: string;
phoneNumber: string;

export const ContactForm = (): JSX.Element => {
   const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
} = useForm<Inputs>();

const formSubmitHandler: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = (
  data: Inputs,
  event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>
) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('form data is', data);
}
```

I am getting an error on formSubmitHandler, "Type '(data: Inputs, event: React.FormEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'SubmitHandler'.  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.  Type 'BaseSyntheticEvent<object, any, any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FormEvent'.  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'FormEvent'."  I am not sure what I am missing to be able to use event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when using the handleSubmit from useForm hook it will prevent the default behavior of the form submission.

```
import {useForm, SubmitHandler} from 'react-hook-form';

interface Inputs {
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
email: string;
phoneNumber: string;

export const ContactForm = (): JSX.Element => {

   const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
} = useForm<Inputs>();

const formSubmitHandler: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = (
  data: Inputs) => {
  console.log('form data is', data);
}

return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(formSubmitHandler)}>
//actual form
</form>
)
}
```

You can see this on the GitHub page
[1]: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/0d565fcf944621f5510da4623129ffbd238f9530/src/logic/createFormControl.ts#L1080

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the react-hook-form document in this link
https://react-hook-form.com/ts

You can wrap your submit function with the *handleSubmit* function returned from the useForm hook, and it will automatically do preventDefault.